# Find indexes of arrayes of values in matrix and replace them with new value

Tags: matlab, matrix, replace, find, sparse-matrix

I have a huge sparse matrix for ex A with n*n size , I want to find indexes of an array B (1*m size) of some values from the huge matrix and replace this values with one value such as x ? I don't want to use loop, how is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: How will you know which array you want to find the index of? Please be more specific with your question.

Comment: @Dan you are right :). Thanks for comment, I edited the question. Do you understand the question? Any idea?

Comment: So this array b that you are searching must be contiguous, unlike in the solution provided by fpe below?

Comment: @Dan: don't you think the OP is looking from something close to my **EDIT** solution?

Comment: @fpe No, I think the OP requires the array to be contiguos. Yours will find all instances off each number from `b` individually in `A`. so if `b` = [1 2], your will remove all `1`s and all `2`s rather than just those that come in pairs directly after each other...

Comment: @Dan: OK, I see...but actually the OP hasn't specified that so far.

Comment: @fpe, yes that's why I asked, otherwise I don't see why your solution wouldn't have been accepted by now

Comment: @Fatime: would you then mind to clarify your point? pehaps with appending a brief example of your target case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
A(find(ismember(A,b))) = NaN
```

***P.S.*** : `NaN` is just as an example, you can tune the value, of course.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The edited answer is true, but first answer is not true and there is a loop, correct the answer,please.

Comment: @Fatime: edited accordingly.